# Serilog log to logz.io from Azure function

Tags: serilog, logz.io

I've got an azure function I need to add logging to logz.io and I'm using Serilog's sink to perform this. On web application with the same key it works in this function not.

here's the program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults().RegisterLinq2DbConnection().RegisterLogzio()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

and here's the extension method

```
 public static class LoggerExtensions
    {
        public static IHostBuilder RegisterLogzio(this IHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureLogging((hostContext, builder) =>
            {
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.LogzIo("key", "Information",
                        new LogzioOptions
                        {
                            RestrictedToMinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug,
                            Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                            LogEventsInBatchLimit = 50
                        }).CreateLogger();

                builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger));
                builder.AddSerilog(Log.Logger,dispose: true);
            });

            return builder;
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something?

In the web application I'm using

```
"WriteTo": [
    
      {
        "Name": "LogzIoDurableHttp",
        "Args": {
          "requestUri": "https://listener-nl.logz.io:8071/?type=app&token=key"
        }
      }
    ],
```